# Return the number of friends in common

Tags: php, sql, select, return

) 
I'm having a problem - and I have been cracking my head against the wall for some time now! 
so I hope that a new set of eyes will help me in this matter..
I'm trying to make a simple counter, that counts how many friends two users have i common, but apparently it is not that simple :-D here is my table.

table

[image: table]

the above table is foreign keys going to the user table, where they use their ids'.

I have tried using selects etc. and I just want to count friends in common.
eg. logged in user has id 14 and the other user has id 4. how many friends do they have in common excluding their own friendship.
thanks in advance :-D

Comment: Can you please explain what your table is showing. What is f_id, u_id1 and u_id2 and all those numbers. I could(as I am sure others reading could) have a guess, but guessing could lead to the wrong answe.

Comment: ahh - yes - sorry..
u_id1 and u_id2 is foreign keys going to the table of users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE T1 
JOIN YOUR_TABLE T2
   ON (T1.u_id2 = T2.u_id2)
WHERE T1.u_id1 = $first_user 
   AND T2.u_id2 = $first_user  
   AND T2.u_id1 = $second_user 
   AND T1.u_id2 = $second_user
```

Comment: It returns zero results

Comment: I got to your answer now - and I just needed to delete the "u.id2s" it now returns the count of common friends